# Java IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexing, bounds, out

I created a little android game but I am getting weird error.

Here is log:

```
    12-31 16:10:22.407: E/AndroidRuntime(12824): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1461
    12-31 16:10:22.407: E/AndroidRuntime(12824): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
    12-31 16:10:22.407: E/AndroidRuntime(12824):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
    12-31 16:10:22.407: E/AndroidRuntime(12824):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
    12-31 16:10:22.407: E/AndroidRuntime(12824):    at **.***.****.GameScreen.updatePaused(GameScreen.java:91)
    12-31 16:10:22.407: E/AndroidRuntime(12824):    at **.***.****.GameScreen.update(GameScreen.java:43)
    12-31 16:10:22.407: E/AndroidRuntime(12824):    at **.***.****.framework.impl.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:39)
    12-31 16:10:22.407: E/AndroidRuntime(12824):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

And here is part of code executed :

```
    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i); ->>> this line
    .
    .
    .
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Is your code multi-threaded?  If so, is it possible that `touchEvents` is getting modified in another thread?

Comment: Are you removing elements from `touchEvents` while iterating over it?

Comment: just test if the value of 'len' returning some value in logger?

Comment: as jeet said above use Eclipse debugger or something similar to step through each line preceding and see how it's changing, it's hard to tell from just the code you've posted

Comment: It is multi-threaded but none of thread doesn't change touchEvent for sure.

Comment: Checking log is irritating.
Sometimes app broke, sometimes not. So I have been playing game for 5 min no with no 'luck' of crushing app...

Comment: The fact that it only crashes sometimes sounds exactly like a race condition caused by multithreading. Are you *absolutely* sure only one thread *ever* touches that field?

Comment: touchEvent is in UI thread and it is just used in game thread without being changed. I think it is not problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are having threading issues you'll have to either synchronize on the collection prior to looping like this

```
synchronize(touchEvents) {
    for(TouchEvent event : touchEvents) {
        //do whatever you want with events
    }
}
```

Or, you can make a local copy of the collection and loop over that, if it's still valid to process events in the collection if they have been removed while you're working on the copy.

Comment: I thought about copy it is more elegant way. I will do it like that if logging doesn't help soon.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way is definitely using enhanced for loop like this

```
for(TouchEvent event : touchEvents) {
    //do whatever you want with events
}
```

Comment: If `touchEvents` is modified in any way during iteration, this will still throw an `ConcurrentModificationException`. It won't actually solve the problem, nor is it "safer".

Comment: Thats true but it is still safer because you can avoid dumb errors like `touchEvents.size() - 1`

Comment: Agreed. Also, it's easier to change the collection type, since the enhanced for-loop works for all `Iterable`s.

Comment: Creating copy of touchEvents list and use it in for-each like above ?

Answer (score 2):

You should always check for NULL.

```
int len = touchEvents != null ? touchEvents.size() : 0
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
```

Comment: Could do it like that also. Thanks!